# What does FOR operator do in Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I was messing around with Spark SQL in the scala repl and received the following error:

```
extraneous input ')' expecting {'ADD', 'AFTER', 'ALL', 'ALTER', 'ANALYZE', 'AND', 'ANTI', 'ANY', 'ARCHIVE', 'ARRAY', 'AS', 'ASC', 'AT', 'AUTHORIZATION', 'BETWEEN', 'BOTH', 'BUCKET', 'BUCKETS', 'BY', 'CACHE', 'CASCADE', 'CASE', 'CAST', 'CHANGE', 'CHECK', 'CLEAR', 'CLUSTER', 'CLUSTERED', 'CODEGEN', 'COLLATE', 'COLLECTION', 'COLUMN', 'COLUMNS', 'COMMENT', 'COMMIT', 'COMPACT', 'COMPACTIONS', 'COMPUTE', 'CONCATENATE', 'CONSTRAINT', 'COST', 'CREATE', 'CROSS', 'CUBE', 'CURRENT', 'CURRENT_ DATE', 'CURRENT_TIME', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', 'CURRENT_ USER', 'DATA', 'DATABASE', DATABASES, 'DBPROPERTIES', 'DEFINED', 'DELETE', 'DELIMITED', 'DESC', 'DESCRIBE', 'DFS', 'DIRECTORIES', 'DIRECTORY', 'DISTINCT', 'DISTRIBUTE', 'DIV', 'DROP', 'ELSE', 'END', 'ESCAPE', 'ESCAPED', 'EXCEPT', 'EXCHANGE', 'EXISTS', 'EXPLAIN', 'EXPORT', 'EXTENDED', 'EXTERNAL', 'EXTRACT', 'FALSE', 'FETCH', 'FIELDS', 'FILTER', 'FILEFORMAT', 'FIRST', 'FOLLOWING', 'FOR', 'FOREIGN', 'FORMAT', 'FORMATTED', 'FROM', 'FULL', 'FUNCTION', 'FUNCTIONS', 'GLOBAL', 'GRANT', 'GROUP', 'GROUPING', 'HAVING ', 'IF', 'IGNORE', 'IMPORT', 'IN', 'INDEX', 'INDEXES', 'INNER', 'INPATH', 'INPUTFORMAT', 'INSERT', 'INTERSECT', 'INTERVAL', 'INTO', 'IS', 'ITEMS', 'JOIN', 'KEYS', 'LAST', 'LATERAL', 'LAZY', 'LEADING', 'LEFT', ' IKE', 'LIMIT', 'LINES', 'LIST', 'LOAD', 'LOCAL', 'LOCATION', 'LOCK', 'LOCKS', 'LOGICAL', 'MACRO', 'MAP', 'MATCHED', 'MERGE', 'MSCK', 'NAMESPACE', 'NAMESPACES', 'NATURAL', 'NO', NOT, 'NULL', 'NULLS', 'OF', 'ON' 'ONLY', 'OPTION', 'OPTIONS', 'OR', 'ORDER', 'OUT', 'OUTER', 'OUTPUTFORMAT', 'OVER', 'OVERLAPS', 'OVERLAY', 'OVERWRITE', 'PARTITION', 'PARTITIONED', 'PARTITIONS', 'PERCENT', 'PIVOT', 'PLACING', 'POSITION', 'PR CEDING', 'PRIMARY', 'PRINCIPALS', 'PROPERTIES', 'PURGE', 'QUERY', 'RANGE', 'RECORDREADER', 'RECORDWRITER', 'RECOVER', 'REDUCE', 'REFERENCES', 'REFRESH', 'RENAME', 'REPAIR', 'REPLACE', 'RESET', 'RESTRICT', 'REV WE', 'RIGHT', RLIKE, 'ROLE', 'ROLES', 'ROLLBACK', 'ROLLUP', 'ROW', 'ROWS', 'SCHEMA', 'SELECT', 'SEMI', 'SEPARATED', 'SERDE', 'SERDEPROPERTIES', 'SESSION_ USER', 'SET', 'MINUS', 'SETS', 'SHOW', 'SKEWED', 'SOME', 'SORT', 'SORTED', 'START', 'STATISTICS', 'STORED', 'STRATIFY', 'STRUCT', 'SUBSTR', 'SUBSTRING', 'TABLE', 'TABLES', 'TABLESAMPLE', 'TBLPROPERTIES', TEMPORARY, 'TERMINATED', 'THEN', 'TO', 'TOUCH', 'TRAILING', 'TRANSACTION', 'TRANSACTIONS', 'TRANSFORM', 'TRIM', 'TRUE', 'TRUNCATE', 'TYPE', 'UNARCHIVE', 'UNBOUNDED', 'UNCACHE', 'UNION', 'UNIQUE', 'UNKNOWN', 'UNLOCK', 'UNSET', 'UPDATE', 'USE', 'USER', 'USING', 'VALUES', 'VIEW', 'VIEWS', 'WHEN', 'WHERE', 'WINDOW', 'WITH', IDENTIFIER, BACKQUOTED_IDENTIFIER}(line 1, pos 36)
```

I realized I had no idea about some of these operators. I fiddled around with one and eventually got it to output something:

```scala
spark.sql("select add from df FOR (select ,add ,none) where select = 1 ").show
```

What does this `FOR` operator do? And what are the operators `PARTITIONS`, `FOLLOWING`, `DISTRIBUTE`, and `GROUPING` used for?

Comment: [Images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data, such as error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `FOR` is a keyword used in some string functions to specify the length and in pivot clause for the values to pivot:

```sql
SELECT substring('Spark SQL' FROM 5 FOR 1)
-- returns 'k'

SELECT overlay('Spark SQL' PLACING 'ANSI ' FROM 7 FOR 0)
-- returns 'Spark ANSI SQL'

-- pivot
SELECT * FROM t
PIVOT (SUM(a) AS a FOR b IN ('x', 'y'))
```

It is also used to alias table columns when used after `from table FOR(...)` which is equivalent to `as tab(...)`:

```sql
SELECT max(x) FROM VALUES (10), (50), (20) FOR(x) -- aliasing table columns
-- above is same as 
SELECT max(x) FROM VALUES (10), (50), (20) AS tab(x)
```

- `FOLLOWING` is a keyword used to specify Window frame boundaries when working with windowing functions:

```sql
ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING
```

- [`DISTRIBUTE BY`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-distribute-by.html) is a clause used to repartition the data based on the input expressions:

```sql
SELECT a, b FROM t DISTRIBUTE BY b
```

- [`GROUPING`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#grouping) is a function that indicates whether a specified column in a GROUP BY is aggregated or not. There is also `GROUPING SET` used with [`GROUP BY`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-groupby.html) clause

You can refer to the official docs [Spark SQL, Built-in Functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/) and [SQL Reference](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax.html). And you can find many examples simply by searching the keywords you want in [Apache Spark Github repo](https://github.com/apache/spark/search?l=SQL&q=FOLLOWING).